# Ping a list of host names and output the results to a csv in powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, csv, ping

I have a large list of hostnames I need to ping to see if they are up or down. I'm not really that great at scripting but I managed to figure this much out:

```
$names = Get-content "hnames.txt"

foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name is up" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$name is down" -ForegroundColor Red
  }
}
```

This gets me what I need but i now need to write out these results to a csv file and i have no idea how to do that.

Please Help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following code instead (I simply altered the write-host calls to CSV formatting) and execute it with "PowerShell.exe script.ps > output.csv"
Note that you must execute it from the folder that contains hnames.txt, or simply change the "hnames.txt" to a full path.

```
$names = Get-content "hnames.txt"

foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name,up"
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$name,down"
  }
}
```

P.S. You can also use the [Out-File Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx) to create the CSV file

Comment: Sweet! This works! Is there a way to have the script itself to print to a csv file instead of piping? I need to give this to a co-worker of mine who would rather just run the script.

Comment: Yeah you can use the `Add-Content` cmdlet instead of the Write-host cmdlet, for example `Add-Content output.csv "$name,up"`

Comment: Now there's functions for writing `CSV` [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7#notes) and [ConvertTo-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7) -- to log pings I found it easier to use `json` like: `Test-Connection -TargetName $targets -Ping -OutVariable ping_results; $ping_results | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress -OutVariable last_export | Out-File -FilePath "log.json" -Append;`

Answer (score 4):

I am a complete newbie to Powershell, so I took this on as a learning task, as I needed a quick and simple way to check a list of PC's for up/down status.  These tweaks were needed to get it to output cleanly to the screen and to a txt file

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content "hnames.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= "$name,up"
   Write-Host "$Name,up"
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name,down"
    Write-Host "$Name,down"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "C:\support\result.csv"
```

Comment: nice and clean. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.  Using a list of computers and -asjob works very well.  The Responsetime property (confusingly the header is "Time(ms)") will be non-null if the host is up.

```
$names = Get-content hnames.txt
test-connection $names -asjob -count 1 | receive-job -wait -auto
```

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address     Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------     -----    --------
COMP001       yahoo.com       74.6.231.21                      32       39
COMP001       microsoft.com   40.113.200.201                   32
```

Lately I do it this way.  It requires threadjobs installed in powershell 5.1.  Or just use get-port.  I stick it in a mymod\mymod.psm1 module file somewhere in $env:psmodulepath.  I can check a classroom in under 10 seconds.

```
function get-pport {  # multi-threaded
  param($list)
  
  $list |
    % { $_ | start-threadjob { get-port $input } -throttlelimit 20 } |
    receive-job -wait -auto
}

function Get-Port {

  Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]]$Hostname='yahoo.com'
  )
  
  begin {   
    $ports = 22,5988,3389,5985
    $ping = New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.ping
    $Timeout = 200 # ms 
  }

  process {
    $hostname | foreach {
      $openPorts = @()
  
      foreach ($port in $ports) {
        $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($_,$port,$null,$null)
        Start-Sleep -Milli $TimeOut
        if($client.Connected) { $openPorts += $port }
        $client.Close()
      }
  
      $result = $Ping.Send($_, $timeout)
      if (! $result) { write-error "hostname $_ not found" }
      $pingstatus = ($result.status -eq 'Success')
  
      New-Object -typename PSObject -Property @{
        HostName = $_
        Port = $openPorts
        Ping = $pingstatus 
      } | select hostname,port,ping
    } # end foreach
  } # end process

}
```

Example:

```
$avid = cat afile.txt
pport $avid

HostName Port          Ping
-------- ----          ----
A006     {3389, 5985}  True
A011     {3389, 5985}  True
A015     {3389}        True
```

Comment: ...did you forget something there js2010? Where is the output?

Comment: @js2010 Seem like you changed the variable and function names? Can you please update your answer?

Comment: @not2qubit I did not.  But you can drop get- from any command.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $Output= @()
    $names = Get-Content ".\input\Servers.txt"
    foreach ($name in $names){
      if (Test-Connection -Delay 15 -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -quiet){
       $Output+= "$name,up"
       Write-Host "$Name,up" -ForegroundColor Green
      }
      else{
        $Output+= "$name,down"
        Write-Host "$Name,down" -ForegroundColor Red
      }
    }
    $Output | Out-file ".\output\result.csv"
```

This is a tad cleaner, and includes the original foreground options but, BTW, the 'delay' switch seems to be ignored -PB

Comment: BTW, Powershell 6 has the wrong options for Test-Connection timeout option "Delay". 'Delay' does NOTHING and the prior timed option no longer exists... so you will be pinging at max speed.... PB