# Check if computer is online, if so, echo "$Computername is online" script

Tags: powershell

let me preface, I am brand new to powershell.  I really just need to get the hang of the syntax and I'll be alright.

Basically, I want this script to parse `computers.txt` file I have with a listed of machines that are comma delimited

`$computernames = Get-Content -Path "c:\scripts\computers.txt"`

Not sure if this is going to format it probably, maybe I need to put `Get-ChildItem` in here somewhere, to make it appear in the loop per item.

I need to put this in a for loop of sorts and have it ping each machine once, and if there is a successful response, I need it to echo "Computername is online" until it reaches the end of the txt file.

I think ping is `Test-Connection` in powershell.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes. Use `foreach` to create the loop and `Test-Connection` to ping the machine. Then `Write-Output` to display a message.

Comment: Ues `Get-Help` to learn about each of those.

Comment: Why does nobody use the searchbox above to find similar/better Q&A before posting? [PowerShell Mass Test-Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30068678/6811411),  [Speed up Test-Connection before Foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24442731/6811411), [Ping a list of host names and output the results to a csv in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493414/6811411)