# Ping computer list

Tags: powershell

I have a list of computers i'm pinging from the command line, and outputting just the computer names to a txt file. I would like to do the same with a powershell script but be able to exclude the computers that fall within the 192.168.100.0/22 cidr when it is pinged.

Comment: What have you try so far? (See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) Also nore that there are already a lot of examples of what you asked for, see e.g. [Ping a list of host names and output the results to a csv in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493414/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cmdlet Test-Connection to ping computers. You can specify an array of ip  to it

```
New-Item "out.txt" -Type File
"IP","IP" | ForEach {
  If (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -EA SilentlyContinue){
   [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($_).HostName >>"out.txt"
  }
}
```

Or you can get input from text file by replacing "IP","IP" with Get-Content "FilePath"

Comment: I don't have a problems getting all the computers that i could ping to a txt file. I really just have an issue with excluding computers that fall within a certain ip range. Sorry i wasn't clear.