# Check if multiple websites are running

Tags: powershell, web

I need to check a couple of hundreds of websites if they are running, redirecting, or offline. Is there any way to check it from Powershell at once?
I have a CSV with hostnames prepared to be used.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating a shell script to read those website URLs from CSV and ping them, use loop or something as required. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259251/powershell-script-to-check-the-status-of-a-url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ping a list of host names and output the results to a csv in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493414/ping-a-list-of-host-names-and-output-the-results-to-a-csv-in-powershell)